# Merge WooCommerce tabs: Orders and Subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm following this tutorial to merge My Account tabs: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-merge-account-tabs/
I want to merge Orders and Subscriptions, thus hide Subscriptions tab and display its content in Orders tab.

So, `unset($items['subscriptions']);` works fine, the tab gets hidden.

But when I do `add_action( 'woocommerce_account_orders_endpoint', 'woocommerce_account_subscriptions' );` it doesn't work, I get `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_account_subscriptions' not found or invalid function name`.

Does anyone happen to know the correct callback function name?

Comment: This depends on which plugin you're using for subscriptions, or if you created this by yourself?

Comment: WooCommerce Subscriptions, this one https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at their code... the callback function is a method of the class `WCS_Query`

So if you do this, it should work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_orders_endpoint', array(new WCS_Query(),'endpoint_content' ) );
```

Comment: Tried that, got ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WCS_Query' not found in...```

Comment: This works for me... Are you sure the plugin is enabled?  What version number?  This is what I see - https://snipboard.io/OSVN4C.jpg

Comment: Ok, found the problem. I was adding the code to a custom plugin, not to functions.php of the theme. It works in functions.php but doesn't work in a custom plugin. Thanks!